# SketchUp export obj with textures - how

Tags: 3d, three.js, webgl, sketchup

Windows 7 (64bit), SketchUp Make 13.0.4812.

**Goal:** convert SketchUp .skp model to `.obj` and load to WebGL using three.js.

**Problem:** sketchup exports model to `.obj` with external textures, and these textures are not loaded by three.js.

**Question:** is it possible to save SketchUp model as one `.obj` file with textures?

Comment: The OBJ format does not embed textures. I'm thinking the real issue where is that the textures are not in the location where tree.js is trying to load them from.

Comment: You may want to try exporting in Collada format (.dae) instead

Comment: Collada format is the most suitable solution for me (embedded textures, easy export and one step loading by three.js).

Comment: FWIW you can do textures with OBJ.  You just need a companion MTL file that references the textures as external files.  It's customary for software that writes OBJ to also write an MTL file with material and texture information.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, .obj is a simple text format. You can't store textures in .obj.
 [Here is an example](http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_loader_obj.html) on how to load the texture from a separate .jpg file.

I copied the important bits:

```js
// texture
var manager = new THREE.LoadingManager();
manager.onProgress = function ( item, loaded, total ) {
  console.log( item, loaded, total );
};
var texture = new THREE.Texture();
var loader = new THREE.ImageLoader( manager );
loader.load( 'textures/ash_uvgrid01.jpg', function ( image ) {
  texture.image = image;
  texture.needsUpdate = true;
} );

// model
var loader = new THREE.OBJLoader( manager );
loader.load( 'obj/male02/male02.obj', function ( object ) {
  object.traverse( function ( child ) {
    if ( child instanceof THREE.Mesh ) {
      child.material.map = texture;
    }
    scene.add( object );
  });
});
```